# Submit form data to Excel spreadsheet that is not readable/writable

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I am creating a form in Microsoft Word with VBA. I have it submitting data to an Excel workbook. I would like to prevent general read/write access to the spreadsheet while still allowing anybody with the Word document to submit the form via VBA. Is this possible?

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share the VBA code with us will help us to understand the theme & allow to modify to make workbook READ ONLY.

Comment: You cannot prevent and allow edition at the same time. I'd recommend to try to deny to list this file in the folder - it become invisible, nevertheless no problems to read/write it when you know its name and access by it directly. Another variant is to use special separate account to access this file, but this looks excess in that task. One more variant is do not use Excel.Application and access the file via ADO or DAO.